# Firebase getRedirectResult() doesn't resolve onInit (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

In my Angular project I am trying to implement Firebase loginWithRedirect() via Google Sign-In. Strange thing is, sometimes the getRedirectResult() method does not return anything after redirecting from successful Google Login.
Even more strange: on the mobile phone it **never** resolves.
In those cases, all I receive is:
{
"credential": null,
"user": null
}

My login method:

```
  async onLogin(isGoogleLogin) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
    await loading.present();
    let user;
    if (isGoogleLogin) {
      await this.authService.loginWithGoogle(); 
      // The upper method just calls: await this.angularFireAuth.signInWithRedirect(new   GoogleAuthProvider());
    } else {
      user = await this.authService.login(this.credentials.value);
    }
    await loading.dismiss();

    if (user) {
      this.buildNavPathAndNav();
    } else {
      this.utilService.showErrorToast('Login error', 'Login failed, please try again');
    }
  }
```

My onInit function on the login screen:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    // Get user if logged in via redirect (e.g. google)
    const user = await this.authService.getRedirectLoginResult();

    // Navigate to home screen
    if (user) { this.buildNavPathAndNav(); };
  }
```

My getRedirectLoginResult function:

```
  async getRedirectLoginResult() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
    await loading.present();

    const userObj = await this.afAuth.getRedirectResult();
    if (!userObj.user) {
      await loading.dismiss();
      return;
    };

    await this.dataService.setCurrentUser(userObj.user);
    await loading.dismiss();
    return userObj.user;
  }
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure out what the solution was?